# foreach and renewcommand

Tags: environments, foreach

I want renew a variable in a foreach loop, but my codes won't work. Please help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\tests{
  \newcommand\mytext{aaa}
  \foreach \i in {bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff}{
    \renewcommand\mytext\i
  }
  \mytext
}
\begin{document}
  \tests
\end{document}\
```

It output string "aaa", not "fff"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\foreach` loop implicitly sets a group. Therefore, the redefinition is lost in the next loop or after the loop. A global definition helps, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\tests{
  \newcommand\mytext{aaa}
  \foreach \i in {bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff}{
    \global\let\mytext\i
  }
  \mytext
}
\begin{document}
  \tests
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]